# How to get back from CForm to ScientificForm?

Tags: syntax, number-representation

Consider a number

```
number = 2.*10^20
```

It is in the representation of `ScientificForm`.

I convert it to C-form:

```
numberc=CForm[number]
```

How to convert it back?

Comment: CForm is just a wrapper. So if you do `numberc[[1]]` you will get back the original number.   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4IWg.png)  I do not know if this is what you meant?

Comment: With `cf = number // CForm` then the `number` is just the first part of the `CForm`, i.e.,  `number === cf[[1]]`

Comment: Thanks, this helped!